# Mobile friendly cards in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an array of objects which contain name and description.
Name is short and few charachters. But description may be vary in length.
I want to display this data inside Cards in my react project. I tried using react-bootstrap.

What I want to do is, I want to show cards with same height and length irrespective to the details inside it. And if space in  one row is not enough for all the cards, then it should go to the next line.

I want this structure to be behaved like row-col in bootstrap.

How do I do this in react js? using react-bootstrap or any other component?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this:

```
1. Container - flex-direction: row
2. Item - max-height and width
3. Item inner - use padding or for example width: 90%. All limits and sizes define in this component. It will prevent different sizes of columns.
```

Here is an example
https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/EKEYob
- than define item inner with specific sizes

/ Define your component Item
and simply map through array with objects.

If you want to use react, import Bootstrap library and use their components

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It was easier to use this solution with my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I used bulma during a little project I was toying with at one point and it helped me do exactly as you described.

https://bulma.io/documentation/components/card/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` for equal height boxes

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex; 
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.list-content {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 1em;
   width: 100%;
}
.list-content p {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, eveniet.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
    
     <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur optio ipsa fuga vel repudiandae impedit illum delectus nihil error animi nobis quaerat quidem, amet, praesentium aspernatur inventore numquam! Totam, dolorem inventore reprehenderit, culpa obcaecati!</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo veniam tempore vero velit deleniti corporis recusandae placeat eum repellendus modi architecto, iste, numquam nulla, praesentium fuga soluta eos consequatur sequi expedita! Ea aspernatur explicabo optio ducimus officia blanditiis voluptas possimus veniam maxime!</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  
    <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum molestiae esse dolore corporis velit fugiat ipsam tempore optio dicta. Magnam iusto facere, maxime! Praesentium quo laborum, deserunt adipisci. Ipsam officia delectus repudiandae, aperiam magnam blanditiis fuga similique.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```